# Is it possible to save a mesh in a .vtk file using openmesh with python or C++?

Tags: python, c++, vtk, openmesh

I am working with openmesh in Python (installed with pip) and in C++ (openmesh version 7.0). I must save a mesh under .vtk extension. Openmesh [documentation](http://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-7.0-Documentation/a03948.html) says it is possible, but as far as I have tried, it does not work. Here is my piece of python code :

```
import openmesh as OM

mesh = OM.TriMesh()

#Add some vertices
vh0 = mesh.add_vertex([0,0,0])
vh1 = mesh.add_vertex([0,1,1])
vh2 = mesh.add_vertex([1,0,1])
vh3 = mesh.add_vertex([1,1,0])

#Add some faces (we are building a tetrahedron here)
mesh.add_face(vh0,vh1,vh2)
mesh.add_face(vh0,vh2,vh3)
mesh.add_face(vh0,vh3,vh1)
mesh.add_face(vh1,vh3,vh2)

OM.write_mesh('TEST_MESH.vtk',mesh)
```

It does not write `TEST_MESH.vtk` in my folder, or anywhere else. When I try with '.ply' or '.om', or any other extension supposedly supported according to openmesh documentation it works just fine. So, I don't get why it does not work, has anybody have any clue? Is '.vtk' extension not supported from openmesh writer after all?

**EDIT :**

Exploring further openmesh GitLab I found that the vtk writer was committed in C++ branch [in 2014](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de:9000/OpenMesh/OpenMesh/commit/377bf721acfddcc6ed56b07dc8dad1385def0b0e), but in a [recent commit](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de:9000/OpenMesh/openmesh-python/commit/5d358812a6ad90bbcf5c74f65edb1fca7624603c#f0327d6d0ac219d8adab85673cc81c02ccdac798) from python-binding branch, some (deleted) info implies vtk writer is not supported.
I am a bit confused, did they give up vtk writter, with no changelog notification? (In that case, one should update their [documentation](http://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-7.0-Documentation/a03948.html))

Thanks for helping,

Charles.

Comment: The VTK writer was indeed disabled in OpenMesh. Alex submitted a patch and the writer is now enabled in the new openmesh-python version [1.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/openmesh/1.1.1/). Note that there's currently only a writer and no reader.

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. This answers my question.